# Does memcached have a pass-through mode?

Tags: caching, architecture, memcached

I'm wondering if it's typical or even supported to "layer" memcached instances.  Say, for example you have two memcached servers, one "local" and one "remote".  Is there a way to request something from the "local" server, such that if there is a cache miss, the request is passed through to the remote server?  That is, the local server requests the item from the remote server, and caches the result locally, and the next request for the item would fetch from the local cache.

Or is the only way to do this, to do something like this in your application code (pseudocode, I hope it's clear):

```
item := get(local, id)
if (!isValid(item)) {
  item = get(remote, id)
  if (isValid(item)) {
    set(local, id, item)
  } else {
    // get the item from somewhere else
  }
}
// do something with item
```

The use that I have in mind would be caching immutable objects, so coherency between the two caches is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pass through functionality in memcached. You would have to do your implementation in the application logic as you have shown in your question.